# The grammar of this "definition" -- Please be noted this could be offensive

Tags: determiners

I always liked Aerosmith and one of their songs, [Rag doll.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv2vx57BYi8)

Anyway, I haven't known up until now exactly what the rag doll means and I now think the song is about [the 3rd definition of this page.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rag%20doll)

Thus said, I can not figure out the structure of the part of the definition in exact way, especially here.

> To have *** so wild that the chick gets all tossed around and like hair is sweat stuck to her face

so ～ that ---- part is fine.

But, is the last part,

> like hair is sweat stuck to her face.

grammatically correct?

What confuses me is, I think the writer is using the word, like, as a conjunction but shouldn't he/she have inserted **her** or **the chick's** after the conjunction "like"?

Thank you in advance for your any kind of assistance with many many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I have read through the lyrics on several websites and cannot find this line. It is in the video version? I didn't listen to the lyrics in your link. But why would they sing a version that is so different then?

Comment: @Lambie Would you please read my question carefully. I am not or did not ask the line in the song but about the name of the song and its meaning. And I just googled what "Rag doll" means and I just found a site which you can see in the link....

Comment: @Kentano Tomono I read it five times. 1) What is a Rag Doll 2) What is the structure of the part of the definition etc. OK 1) A rag doll is a children's doll made of rags. 2) The sentence as posted makes no sense. My question is this: You claim the line is from an Aerosmith song but I can't find that line in any of the online versions of the Aerosmith song called Rag Doll.

Comment: @Lambie Kindly read this part -- Thus said, **I can not figure out the structure of the part of the definition** in exact way, especially here.-- I am ( was ) not asking the line of the song but the **line of the urban dictionary**. ^^

Comment: Well, that's why you sent us on a wild goose chase. You mention the Aerosmith song and then quote the Urban Dictionary. It simply was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not grammatically correct, but then I wouldn't expect much precision from the "Urban Dictionary". This is not a dictionary at all, but a series of definitions submitted by users on which others users vote.  It is occasionally accurate, but sometimes it's just the meaning in that user's region or dialect.

It's not bad as a *reference* if you don't know what some slang might mean, but it's not any kind of *authority*.

"Rag doll", as a metaphor for wild sex, is not a common slang term.  The song was written in 1987, and perhaps it had some meaning among rock musicians back then, but more likely Aerosmith made up the term for the song. Their music is not very *deep*, after all.

Anyway "all tossed around and like hair is stuck to her face" is a kind of vernacular way to say "it is like a chick who is tossed around and ends up with her hair stuck to her face, like a doll's hair."

Personally, I think someone is just guessing and this isn't the actual meaning of "rag doll" in the song.  Sometimes musicians just make up things because they sound good.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51462/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-the-grammar-of-this-definition-please-be-not).